# the nvidia gpu not detected, even try to enable/disable igpu and primary display from BIOS

Tags: gpu, nvidia, hdmi, motherboard, asus-xtion

I am having Asus H81M-CS motherboard and i have attached the nvidia gpu , but motherboard not detecting that, motherboard only using integrated graphics.
I have event tried with enable/disable the igpu and primary display from the bios but when pc starts it changed to auto again, and motherboard not able to detect nvidia gpu.
I event tried to check nvidia gpu with another motherboard, there its working fine, so the main problem lies with the asus motherboard/or bios setting of it.
I tried with every possible combination in bios settings but still does'nt work
Please HELP...

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You should mention which GPU you are using. If the GPU needs extra power with 6 pin / 8 pin and extra watts are required. Definitely there will be issues. Mention your available power supply as well in your casing.

Comment: my gpu is nvidia 710, it was working perfectly with the same asus motherboard , but i set bios to load default since after that it stoped working

Comment: Go into your Bios, Advanced Mode,System Agent Configuration and check Graphics configuration.
Here you can force PCIE to be your primary display.

Comment: I already tried that to set primary display PCIE but when i save settings and pc boots then it resets to auto.

Comment: Then, your CMOS battery could be problem which is not saving the settings. If you can replace battery and save settings, should work.

Comment: I have tried to replace CMOS battery with new but still facing same problem.

Comment: It saves other changes in bios, but only reset the primary display setting to auto.

Comment: PCI-E should pick. if this is CPU in setting than it should pick the GPU on board by default. else NVIDIA should be picked by pcie settings